# Bluetooth Ubuntu 18.10 - Can't turn on

Tags: suspend, bluetooth, 18.10

I'm using laptop HP, sometime bluetooth turn off itself.
When I suspend and turn on again, it works.

I try to fix but its did'nt work.
My bluez version is 5.50

`root@jarvis:~# bluetoothctl
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# power off
Changing power off succeeded
[bluetooth]# power on
Failed to set power on: org.bluez.Error.Failed
[bluetooth]#`